# How to disable php file being execute and enable after install

Tags: php, installation

I have a login and register php script with installation folder. But my index.php can be access even the user not yet install the script. How to lock the index file being access and force them to install the script first then they can access the index.

Thanks for help me

Comment: 1. If the install script exists, refuse to run. 2. The last step of an otherwise successful install is deleting the install script. Scripts that don't exist don't run.

Comment: How to achieve this? What function to use?

Comment: 1. [`file_exists()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php) 2. [`unlink()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php)

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like this to detect the install script and block the index from running:

```
<?php 

// Put this at the top of index.php
if (file_exists('install.php')) {
    die('You must run and delete install.php');
}
```

**Edit 1**

This also works with directories:

```
<?php 

// Put this at the top of index.php
if (file_exists('./install')) {
    die('You must run and delete ./install directory');
}
```

Comment: How about if they not install the script and direct to rename the install.php or folder? They can access the index without installing it?

Comment: In that case you need some other way of checking if the script was installed. For example a field in the database or a special lock or config file.

Answer (score -1):

I used sometimes session variable to make authorization across my php files. I used it like this:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['install']) || $_SESSION['install'] = 0) {
//prevent install
}
else {
//install statement
}
```

then if the user logs in or register:

```
$_SESSION['install'] = 1;
```

hope it helps